# Trigger befor insert

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert a control on the data that insert in a table? In a way that satisfies a specific condition provided, otherwise not

```
drop function Presente;
delimiter //
create function Presente( Persona_Da_Cercare varchar(16), Data_Legge date) returns int
begin

    declare risultato int;

    select count(*) into risultato
    from PARLAMENTARI_IN_CARICA as pic
    where Persona_Da_Cercare = pic.Persona and data_Legge >= pic.Data_Eletto;

    if risultato = 0
    then
        select count(*) into risultato
        from STORICO_PARLAMENTARI as sp
        where Persona_Da_Cercare = sp.Persona and data_Legge >= sp.Data_Inizio and data_Legge <= sp.Data_Fine;
    end if;
    return risultato;

end//


set @ultima_legge bigint;
set @ultimo_parlamentare varchar(16);
set @data_legge date;


drop trigger if exists Ultimo_Voto;
delimiter $$
create trigger Ultimo_Voto before insert on VOTO_PALESE
for each row
begin

    set @ultima_legge = new.Legge;
    set @ultimo_parlamentare = new.parlamentare;
    set @data_legge = (select Data_Approvazione from LEGGI where Cod_Legge = new.Legge);

end $$


drop trigger if exists Controllo_Voto_Palese;
delimiter $$
create trigger Controllo_Voto_Palese after insert on VOTO_PALESE
for each row
BEGIN

    IF Presente(@ultimo_parlamentare, @data_legge) = 0 THEN
        delete from VOTO_PALESE where Legge = @ultima_legge AND Parlamentare = @ultimo_parlamentare;
    END IF; 

END $$


insert into VOTO_PALESE(Legge, Parlamentare, Voto) values(770, 'MSRMRC01C14L378X', 'astenuto');
```

when I run the code it gives me this error

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'voto_palese' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I don't understand where the problem is

Comment: the error message is clear you can't update delete or insert into the same table that fired the trigger.

Comment: okay, but then it is impossible to check the data that I want to insert?

Comment: When you insert the a new row, he trigger fies you can chekc every column with NEw.columnname, and also modify it. What you can't do is delete in the same table, or update or insert. Use If NEW.column = 1 then or SET NEW.column = column +1